# Photoshop save location

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've been trying to get Photoshop to save files in particular folders but it's always saving in the wrong location.

This is occurring no matter how I try to save when using export to web; normal Save As seems fine.

I'm running the latest Mac OS and the latest Photoshop.

I've just tried to save a `.psd` in /Volumes/Backup/Websites/Card Hoarder Cards but it actually saved in /Users/ceriturner on the first attempt and the second attempt it saved in /Users/ceriturner/Downloads.

Answer (score 3):

## For the MacOS

The Finder & file pickers should remember per app, per save type, the last-used location.
If you want finer granularity, have a look at [Default Folder X](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/index.html) or use the Finder's own mechanism of dragging the desired location from the desktop to the file picker [which requires you have room to be able to see it] Default Folder can click through any windows in the way.

[Default Folder X](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/index.html) will also allow you to "spring" to *specific* locations in open/save dialogs based on the active application. You can set all open/save dialogs for Photoshop to show one directory, or rebound to the last directory.

In addition, [Default Folder X](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/index.html) will add a "Favorites" menu to open/save dialog windows to give you "shortcuts" to commonly used directories.

Comment: Default Folder X is indeed amazing, saves tons of times. I really miss it on Windows.

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy - yup, it's one of my "How do you use a computer without it?" utilities. Had it since it was on System 8 or 9.

Comment: I could not work effectively without Default Folder. I'm shocked Apple hasn't purchased it or stole it's functionality to date (like they've done with other shareware). I've been DefaultFolder since the OS9 days. Hope the edit was okay.. if not rollback please. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

**1.** I note your proposed save path starts with `/Volumes...` you need to be very sure you have that filepath correct, ***and*** that you do *not* have duplicate mount points for that given volume (this does happen in Mac OS sometimes) which you need to check in Terminal by traversing to that directory and listing all mounted volumes - if there are duplicates, you'll see them, and if there are, that will be a question best posted to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions not **GD.SE**.

**2.** I also note that the name of the Volume to which you wish you write your save for web files is Backup... if indeed that **is** an identified Time Machine Backup volume, the directories may well be permissions-protected, correctly preventing Photoshop from writing there, and you may be able to write to that location by drag n drop for the default only because you're operating from an improperly-elevated user account; I would establish a target area for these files which is *not* in a Backup volume.

Bear in mind that if indeed that volume is in use for backups, and you are writing changes *to* that volume, **a)** those files are not themselves backed up and **b)** sheer luck is all that's kept you from a corrupted backup.

**3.** This issue is in fact squarely out-of-scope as tech support - see https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: None of those links work for me. For 2. Its not a backup drive, it used to be but I haven't renamed it yet.

Comment: Thanks for letting m,e know about the links - they're now fixed!